# Proofs involving positive real numbers

Tags: inequality, approximation, inner-products, random, real-numbers

I have two questions related to positive real numbers:

1. If **a** and **b** are two vectors of positive random integers (no specific statistical distribution) and size *N* by 1 , we want to prove that the inner product can be approximated as:

<**a**, **b**> = sum(**a**) sum(**b**)/N

**a** and **b** are independent but not necessarily identically distributed and N can be as large as needed. checking this in Matlab, it seems to work all the time, except when either or both of **a** and **b** contain negative values.

2. We have c1 and c2 are positive scalar constants, while **x**, **y** and **z** are vectors of size *N* by 1 each containing positive real values. If (Matlab notations)

c1 sum(**x**.***y**./**z.^2**) > c2 sum(**y**./**z.^2**),

is it possible to prove that

c1 sum(**x**.***y**./**z.^3**) > c2 sum(**y**./**z.^3**)?

Any form of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For any vector $\mathbf x$ let $r^k(\mathbf x)$ be the vector obtained by rotating the components by $k$ positions. Then $\sum\mathbf a\cdot\sum\mathbf b=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\langle \mathbf a,r^k(\mathbf b)\rangle$. Hence at least if the distribution for the various components are the same and are independent (but otherwise unspecified), the approximation $\langle \mathbf a,\mathbf b\rangle=\frac 1N\sum \mathbf a\sum\mathbf b$ is somewhat justified: It is the *expected* scalar product between random coordinate permutations of the given vectors.

Comment: Thanks Hagen for your answer. I guess you mean $\sum\mathbf a\cdot\sum\mathbf b=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\langle \mathbf r^k(\mathbf a),\mathbf b\rangle$? Also check the new explanations added to Q1.

Comment: @TareqAhmed Yeah, I should use the notation I introduce somewhere ;)

Comment: @TareqAhmed I do not assume that $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are identically distributed, only that the $b_i$ (or the $a_i$) are i.i.d. - Without this, the estimate may be terribly off: If $N=2$ and $a_1,b_1$ are uniform random $\in\{100,101\}$ and $a_2,b_2$ are uniform random in $\{1,2\}$, then $\frac1N\sum \mathbf a\sum\mathbf b\le 5304.5$ whereas $\langle\mathbf a,\mathbf b\rangle \ge 10001$.